# How to Efficiently convert C/C++ logic into python?

Tags: python, c++, c, python-2.7

I have a .cpp code as below in which I am copying of some values of matrix_1 to matrix_2.

**(NOTE : Initially matrix_2 is copy of matrix_1.)**

```
    num_of_row_of_matrix_1 = 400
    num_of_col_of_matrix_1 = 700
    for (int Row = 0; Row < num_of_row_of_matrix_1; Row += 2)
        {
            for (int Col = 0; Col < num_of_col_of_matrix_1; Col += 2)
            {
                matrix_2[Row + 1][Col] = matrix_1[Row][Col + 1];
            }
        }
```

Now the same code I have implemented in python-2.7 like below,

```
for Row in range(len(matrix_1)/2):
        Row *= 2
        for Col in range(len(matrix_1[0])/2):
            Col *= 2
            matrix_2[Row + 1, Col] = matrix_1[Row, Col + 1]
```

The matrix in python is like

```
array([[1, 2, 3, ...,  33,  37,  36],
       [4, 5, 6, ...,  25,  16,  26],
       [2, 4, 7, ...,  37,  32,  36],
       ..., 
       [ 35, 106,  36, ..., 151,  37, 141],
       [114, 179, 119, ..., 2, 165, 133],
       [ 37, 111,  34, ..., 144,  39, 139]], dtype=uint8)
```

The conversion is about 4 time slower in python than in cpp.

Is there any efficient way to do the same in python?

Let me know if you need further information for clarification.

Comment: That's not how you index in either language. Post real code.

Comment: I'm surprised Python is *only* four times slower. If you're expecting Python to be as fast as C++ you're fighting a losing battle here. Your only options are other Python interpreters or using a C++ module for Python.

Comment: @tadman, I don't want faster than c++, but I just don't want that much difference in processing time.

Comment: Otherwise you can use stride of `range()` function: `range(0, num_of_row_of_matrix_1 - 1, 2)` instead of multiplying by 2.

Comment: @molbdnilo, really I am indexing like this. If this is not the efficient way, then please suggest me the efficient way.

Comment: You're comparing to C++ which is generally acknowledged as the fastest in most situations. You're complaining your pick-up truck can't keep up with a Ferrari. You're also using Python 2.7, not Python 3.6, which does have performance improvements. Or [PyPy](https://pypy.org). Or [CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython). Are you making this hard on purpose?

Comment: @tadman it seems the author is expecting to see if there are any other better way improving performance.

Comment: There's no C/C++ language. A `.cpp` source file strongly suggests C++, but the code shown doesn't make sense in either language (the comma doesn't do what you might expect here). Please decide for one language and remove the other tag, and then fix the code, thanks.

Comment: You can use a numerical library like numpy and its broadcasting/slicing features. It will improve the performance greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for Row in range(len(matrix_1)/2):
        Row *= 2
        for Col in range(len(matrix_1[0])/2):
            Col *= 2
            matrix_2[Row + 1, Col] = matrix_1[Row, Col + 1]
```

Actually, the above code I wrote in a function which I was calling again and again. I asked the question to improve it.

In this code, repeatedly calling of this `matrix_2[Row + 1, Col] = matrix_1[Row, Col + 1]` was the time consuming, which is nothing but the checking index and copying to another matrix.

`x = np.arange (0, num_of_row_of_matrix_1*num_of_col_of_matrix_1).reshape(num_of_row_of_matrix_1, num_of_col_of_matrix_1)
h1, w1 = np.where (np.logical_and ( ((x/num_of_col_of_matrix_1)%2 == 0), (x%2 == 1))) 
h2, w2 = np.where (np.logical_and ( ((x/num_of_col_of_matrix_1)%2 == 1), (x%2 == 0)))`

This gave me the index of what I have to copy. Since these index was fixed that I need to copy, so I kept it outside the function. Then, in the function I am just copying the selected index like, `matrix_2[h2, w2] = matrix_1[h1, w1]` which is not taking time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like these are NumPy arrays. If so, you can do

```
matrix_2[1::2, ::2] = matrix_1[::2, 1::2]
```

to avoid the overhead of Python-level loops and wrapper object construction.